# Excel Array Java

Tags: parsing, random

I imported my excel file into Java. I am now trying to randomly pick 5 people from my data. How would I go about doing that... Here is my code that I have so far.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Rewards {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        String fileName = "C:/Users/Jordan/Desktop/Project5.csv";
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String strLine = null;
        StringTokenizer st = null;
        int lineNumber = 0, tokenNumber = 0;

        while((fileName = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lineNumber++;
            String[] result = fileName.split(",");
            for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++) {
                System.out.println(result[x]);
             }
        }
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with a `Random` instance.  How else can you do anything pseudo-randomly in any programming language?